# Scala 2.10 - compiler bug?

Tags: scala

Is this a compiler bug?

```
class A(val pf: PartialFunction[Int, Int])
class B extends A({
  case 5 => 3
  case _ => 2
})

println(new B)

java.lang.VerifyError: (class: Main$$anon$1$B, method: <init> signature: (LMain$$anon$1;)V) Expecting to find object/array on stack
```

I'm using Scala 2.10 RC3 and Java 7u9

edit: forgot the "new B" at the end of my code. Without that the error doesn't occur

Comment: Cannot reproduce on 2.9.2 so yes, it looks like a bug.

Comment: same error on 2.10.0-RC5

Answer (score 1):

Here's an [issue](https://issues.scala-lang.org/browse/SI-5812) which looks rather similar, including As and Bs. I usually save As for type params, which is how I know I'm not coding in Java.

Answer (score -1):

Upgrade to Scala-2.10-RC3 - it works here!

**EDIT**

```
class B extends A (new PartialFunction[Int, Int]{
  def apply(v: Int) = v match {
    case 3 => 4
    case _ => 0
  }
  def isDefinedAt(v: Int) = true 
})
```

Comment: Low sesnse of humor among us =)